# RDP "ClientName" Environment Variable is null, if run as administrator

Tags: environment-variables, rdp, runas

We have developed a windows application and deployed in terminal server / citrix environment.

We have used the Enviornment.GetEnvironmentVariable("CLIENTNAME") for getting the client name 
from where the RDP is accessed.

If I run the application with normal privilege (double cliking the application), then i am getting 
correct value in the "ClientName" Env Variable.

But when I run the same application with administrator privilege (right click and run as administrator), 
then then "ClientName" Env Variable returns null.

Note: I wrote a small application and get all the environment variables exists in the virtual machine (RDP) 
using "Environment.GetEnvironmentVariables()". "ClientName" Env variables is shown only when it is executed with normal privilege 
and the same variable is hidden if executed with administrator privilege.

Can anyone let us know why the "ClientName" Env variable is hidden on administrator privilege?

Regards,
Guru

Comment: I'm having the same issue.  Did you manage to find a solution?

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like this might be your problem:

> When connecting remotely with Remote Desktop Connection, the
>   environment variables CLIENTNAME and SESSIONNAME are added to each
>   process that is started.
>
> If you set the Folder Option "Launch folder windows in a separate
>   process" and later launch an application from an additional Explorer
>   window, the application will not see these additional environment
>   variables.

To fix the issue:

> If your application relies on these variables, remove the folder
>   option "Launch folder windows in a separate process".

[image: Explorer image]

MS Article: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2509192

Answer (score 1):

```
$sessionID = (Get-Process -PID $pid).SessionID

$PC = (Get-ItemProperty -path ("HKCU:\Volatile Environment\" + $sessionID) -name "CLIENTNAME").CLIENTNAME
```